# Is the highest probability path is always the most direct in this Markov process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, binomial-distribution

**Markov Process**

The state $A_{t+1}$ at time $t+1$ is distributed as Binomial($N$,$\frac{A_{t}}{N}$). In this Markov process there are therefore two absorbing states $0$ and $N$.

**Question**

To go from one state (say $A_0=68$) to another (say $A_t=70$), there is an infinite possible number of paths, each of them are associated with a certain probability.

- *Is the highest probability path always the one-step path?*
- *Is there a rule to determine whether the highest probability path is the one-step path?*

**Answering the first question through computational methods**

For $N=1000$, $A_0=350$ and $A_{end}=800$. The following is coded in R

```
A0 = 350
Aend = 800
N = 1000

reps = 1e5 # This is the number of replicates to draw the histogra. 'reps = 1e5' will take a bit long. Might be better to use '1e4' if you are willing to reproduce.
lens = numeric(reps)

for (rep in 1:reps)
{
    if (rep %% 100 == 0) cat(paste0(rep/reps," %\n"))
    A = A0
    len = 0
    while(TRUE)
    {
        A = rbinom(1,N,A/N)
        len = len + 1
        if (A == Aend) 
        {
            lens[rep] = len         
            break
        }
        if (A == 0 | A == N)
        {
            lens[rep] = NA
            break
        }
    }
}

hist(lens,breaks=50)
```

[image]

```
t = table(lens)
print(paste("The most often used path length is",names(t)[t==max(t)]))
```

The most often used path length is 428.

Note that I haven't checked for potential biased due to round off error but I would tend to think the result is trustful.

Comment: "There are N balls total" "we draw N balls with replacement" Same N?

Comment: Yes. We ensure that from one time step to the next the population of balls remain constant. Only the frequency of balls of black balls $\frac{A_t}{N}$ varies through time. I edited this clarification info in my post. Thanks

Comment: How is the process to 'renew' the population? I mean, for example ($N=10$), if for $t=0$ we have $5$ blac balls, and we take all $10$ of them (which means all $5$ black balls and other ball are removed), how is the process to refill the urn? How many black balls? etc etc, (sorry, but actually I think this is not a markov chain afterall, I cannot understand how the previous step contribute some information to the next step except for same $N$)

Comment: @RizkyRezaFujisaki I am not sure I understand what is unclear. Let me know if the following helps. Imagine at time $t$ you have $A_t=7$ black balls and $N-A_t=3$ white balls. You sample with replacement $N$ balls $\left(N=10\right)$. At the next step with probability $p_{7,8}={10 \choose 8} \left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^{8}\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{2}≈0.23$ there are $8$ black balls (always out of $N$) in the population of balls. (The above equation is simply a binomial distribution in which specific values has been entered). Does it help?

Comment: I think the description in terms of balls is not actually that helpful here, except perhaps as motivation. Mathematically, the point is that $A_{t+1}$ is distributed as Binomial($N,A_t/N$) and is independent of anything other than $A_t$. That said, I would actually be surprised if the maximum probability path were always single-step. I would think that it would typically take a few steps to go from, say, $A_t=1$ to $A_s=100$ when $N=100$. Perhaps you could try simulation: it would be easy to make a histogram of the lengths of paths from $A_t=a$ to $A_s=b$ for certain fixed $a,b,N$.

Comment: @Ian thanks for your comment. I edited my post and I agree it is much simpler and easier to understand in the current form.

Comment: You also might consider looking into transition path theory, which gives a way to avoid wasting too much computing time on paths that lack the property that you want (e.g. that get absorbed before they hit the intermediate state of interest).

Comment: @Ian I have now also answered the (now first) question through numerical methods.

Comment: Cool. I suppose one flaw in this way of looking at things compared to your original question is that there is just one single step path, but there are many paths that take many steps. Perhaps 214 is the most likely path length with the numbers you chose partly by virtue of the sheer number of paths of that length.

Comment: @Remi.b Ah I see, after reading your edited explanation, it is really clear, thank you, well, time to start thinking, I will let you know if i can help to solve your problem (this is difficult but interesting, sorry if I am not as good as other people)